# Creating a read stream over a string

Tags: unit-testing, rust

I have a function that takes an input stream, processes its data, and then returns something, basically a more complicated version of this:

```
fn read_number_from_stream(input: &mut io::BufRead) -> io::Result<u32> {
  // code that does something useful here
  Ok(0)
}
```

Now I want to write a test for this function.

```
#[test]
fn input_with_zero_returns_zero() {
  let test_input = read_from_string("0\n");
  assert_eq!(Ok(0), read_number_from_stream(test_input));
}
```

How do I implement `read_from_string`? Older versions of Rust apparently provided `std::io::mem::MemReader`, but the entire `std::io::mem` module seems to be gone in more recent versions of Rust (I'm using the unstable 1.5 branch).

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The documentation for each trait lists the available implementations. [Here's the documentation page for `BufRead`.](http://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/io/trait.BufRead.html#implementors) We can see that `&'a [u8]` (a slice of bytes) implements `BufRead`. We can obtain a slice of bytes from a string and pass a mutable reference to that slice to `read_number_from_stream`:

```
use std::io;

fn read_number_from_stream(input: &mut impl io::BufRead) -> io::Result<u32> {
    // code that does something useful here
    Ok(0)
}

fn read_from_string(s: &str) -> &[u8] {
    s.as_bytes()
}

fn main() {
    let mut test_input = read_from_string("0\n");
    read_number_from_stream(&mut test_input);
}
```

If the buffer is not expected to contain UTF-8, or you just care about a particular ASCII-compatible subset of characters, you may want to define the test input as a byte string, rather than as a normal string. A byte string is written like a normal string, prefixed with `b`, e.g. `b"0\n"`. The type of a byte string is `&[u8; N]`, where `N` is the length of the string. Since that type doesn't implement `BufRead`, we need to cast it to `&[u8]`.

```
fn main() {
    let mut test_input = b"0\n" as &[u8];
    read_number_from_stream(&mut test_input);
}
```